# Start a service on available network for Android N?

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver, android-internet, android-7.0-nougat

I realise that the broadcastReceiver to check internet connectivity is no longer supported in the latest api so what can I use instead ? Do I absolutely have to work in the foreground ? and if so how is it done ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/background-optimization.html